# using dispatcher to update UI from class with async methods in wpf

Tags: c#, class, asynchronous

I've got a class with manage data, and this class has a ObservableCollection which is bind in UI menu. The problem is that the observable collection loads data, but my UI does not show it.

My class is like this

```
public class DAL : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DAL()
    {
        this.unity = new UnitOfWork(@"http://192.168.0.173/vocalcontactapi");
    }

    private UnitOfWork unity;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<EstadosAgente> estadosPausa = new ObservableCollection<EstadosAgente>();
    public ObservableCollection<EstadosAgente> EstadosPausa
    {
        get { return this.estadosPausa; }
    }

    public async Task<bool> GetAgentStatesAsync()
    {
        await awaitGetAgentStatesTask();
        OnPropertyChanged("EstadosPausa");
        return true;
    }

    private Task awaitGetAgentStatesTask()
    {
        //UnitOfWork unity = new UnitOfWork(Properties.Settings.Default.restServer);
        NameValueCollection parms = new NameValueCollection();
        parms.Add("servicioId", "1");
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                var estados = unity.EstadosAgente.GetAll(parms).Where(q => q.habilitado == true).Select(p => p).ToList();
                if (estados == null)
                    return;

                estados.ForEach(x =>
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        this.EstadosPausa.Add(x); //*** I think here is the problem***
                    }));
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And mainWindow I have a Property of class DAL:

```
private DAL data = new DAL();
public DAL Data { get{ return this.data}}
```

In my menu I've got next:

```
  <Menu Grid.Row="1">
            <MenuItem Header="uno" ItemsSource="{Binding DAL.EstadosPausa}" Click="DataBoundMenuItem_Click">
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding estado}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding}" />
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

Obviously, all properties of the loaded data are correct. Any help please?

Comment: Are you saying that the UI *never* shows the data, or that the UI does not show the data until after the entire collection is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's few things in this code which makes me "itchy" but anyway...

You have `public DAL Data` property but you are binding to `DAL.EstadosPausa`. You need to bind to `Data.EstadosPausa` and that'll solve it. You'll see all binding errors in your debuggers `Output` window.

---

Here, consider this simplified yet 100% working version of your code base. Now you are fooling around with `async/await`s, returning `Task<bool>` and `Dispatching` work to UI thread for no good reason (that is obvious from your example).

**XAML**

```
<Menu Grid.Row="1">
    <MenuItem Header="Uno" ItemsSource="{Binding Data.EstadosPausa}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Estado}"/>
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding}" />
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Dal _data = new Dal();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        _data.GetAgentStatesAsync(); // Fire Task away, no time to wait!!1
    }

    public Dal Data { get { return _data; } }  
}

public class EstadosAgente
{
    public string Estado { get; set; }
}

public class Dal : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Task GetAgentStatesAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // I'm a long running operation...
                var estados = new List<EstadosAgente>
                    {
                        new EstadosAgente { Estado = "Estado 1" },
                        new EstadosAgente { Estado = "Estado 2" }
                    };
                EstadosPausa = new ObservableCollection<EstadosAgente>(estados);
                OnPropertyChanged("EstadosPausa");
            });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EstadosAgente> EstadosPausa { get; private set; }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged; // <- always assign to local variable!
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```